# lnk1114 Cannot overwrite the original file "xxx.lib", error code 32

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, lnk

lnk1114 Cannot overwrite the original file "xxx.lib", error code 32.
it happened in vs2017.
Microsoft does not have this in its error codes.
actually i put "xxx.lib" in the output folder like "debug.win32".
Did I make a mistake?

Comment: Is the program still running? Did you make `xxx.lib` write-only somehow?

Comment: its not running.File permissions are fully controlled

Comment: It's generally an error to move files around. Instead tell Visual Studio where the files are (or where to write them). Can you delete this file? Why did you move it in the first place?

Comment: actually i try to delete this file. but it is still not working.lnk1104 cant open the file.move it to somewhere else is not working too.

Comment: In fact Microsoft does document error code 32: it is a sharing violation, indicating that the file is in use by another process

Answer (score 0):

The Handle application from SysInternals (now Microsoft) can help you locate the process that is using a file (although it gets harder if the file is in use through a network share).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle

It is a command-line utility that must be run in an elevated prompt.

The Process Explorer utility (Task Manager on steroids), also from SysInternals, also features a "Find Handle or DLL" command (in the Find menu), that performs the same job, if you prefer graphical tools.